# Split string without delimeters

Tags: r, regex, separator, strsplit

I have df which contains a column with metro lines. The problem is that L9N and L10N appear sometimes in the same row and I want to split them into two different rows. I have been trying many things but I can't figure out how to do it.

| Type | Lines | Year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| METRO | L5 | 1959 |
| METRO | L5 | 1959 |
| METRO | L5 | 1959 |
| METRO | L9NL10N | 2009 |
| METRO | L9S | 2016 |
| METRO | L10S | 2018 |
| METRO | L10N | 2010 |
| METRO | L4 | 1926 |
| METRO | L1 | 1926 |
| METRO | L1 | 1926 |

Comment: Apart from "L9NL10N", are there other "Lines" with such issues? So that we can post more generalised solutions. Do metro line names always start with letter "L"?

Comment: Related post https://stackoverflow.com/q/41912524/680068

Comment: All lines start with "L" and only lines 9 and 10 have such issues, but it appears in two cases: "L9NL10N" and "L9SL10S"

Answer (score 4):

A `data.table` oneliner.
It uses a [lookbehind-lookahead regex `"(?<=\[NS])(?=L)"`](https://regex101.com/r/VyMvcQ/1) to identify splitting points (between capital N (or S) and capital L), and then splits those rows, keeping the delimeter.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)[, .(Lines = unlist(tstrsplit(Lines, "(?<=[NS])(?=L)", perl = TRUE))), by = .(Type, Year)][]

#     Type Year Lines
# 1: METRO 1959    L5
# 2: METRO 1959    L5
# 3: METRO 1959    L5
# 4: METRO 2009   L9N
# 5: METRO 2009  L10N
# 6: METRO 2016   L9S
# 7: METRO 2018  L10S
# 8: METRO 2010  L10N
# 9: METRO 1926    L4
#10: METRO 1926    L1
#11: METRO 1926    L1
```

edit:
Use regex `"(?<=[A-Z])(?=L)"` for splitting after any capital letter `[A-Z]`, followed by the capital letter `L`.

Comment: updated code, to the S followed by an L is also a delimeter.

Comment: OP clarified it always starts with "L", so we can just look for L and split: `strsplit(c("L5", "L9NL10N", "L9SL10S"), '(?<=.)(?=[L])', perl = TRUE)`

Comment: That is correct... but what if a line also ends with an L , like `L9LL10N` (ok, now I'm just making up usecases ;-) )

Comment: I think @jpiversen guessed it right, last letter is Cardinal directions = N,E,S,W. So metro going Louth is unlikely on Earth. :D

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tidy and efficient way for data.frames:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(Lines = stringr::str_extract_all(Lines, "L\\d*([NSEW]?)")) %>% 
  tidyr::unnest(Lines)

#> # A tibble: 11 × 3
#>    Type  Lines  Year
#>    <chr> <chr> <dbl>
#>  1 METRO L5     1959
#>  2 METRO L5     1959
#>  3 METRO L5     1959
#>  4 METRO L9N    2009
#>  5 METRO L10N   2009
#>  6 METRO L9S    2016
#>  7 METRO L10S   2018
#>  8 METRO L10N   2010
#>  9 METRO L4     1926
#> 10 METRO L1     1926
#> 11 METRO L1     1926
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

It will work for any duplicated line following the pattern: `L <som number> <possible one of N, S, E or W>`.

##### Data

```r
df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~Type, ~Lines, ~Year,
  "METRO",  "L5", 1959,
  "METRO",  "L5", 1959,
  "METRO",  "L5", 1959,
  "METRO",  "L9NL10N",  2009,
  "METRO",  "L9S",  2016,
  "METRO",  "L10S", 2018,
  "METRO",  "L10N", 2010,
  "METRO",  "L4", 1926,
  "METRO",  "L1", 1926,
  "METRO",  "L1",   1926
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(Lines, sep="(?<=[N|S])(?=L)")

#> # A tibble: 11 × 3
#>    Type  Lines  Year
#>    <chr> <chr> <int>
#>  1 METRO L5     1959
#>  2 METRO L5     1959
#>  3 METRO L5     1959
#>  4 METRO L9N    2009
#>  5 METRO L10N   2009
#>  6 METRO L9S    2016
#>  7 METRO L10S   2018
#>  8 METRO L10N   2010
#>  9 METRO L4     1926
#> 10 METRO L1     1926
#> 11 METRO L1     1926
```